# android project build failed with an exception. Unable to get Gradle wrapper properties

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I cloned android project from github https://github.com/Xlythe/Calculator. This project is a calculator which has in playmarket. So I think, it must be work. But I have same problem. I get the following error when I am trying to import the project.

> Unable to get Gradle wrapper properties from: C:\AndroidApps\Calculator\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties. Would you like to recreate the wrapper using the latest supported Gradle version?
>   Click 'OK' to recreate files, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of a local Gradle distribution.

And I get the following error when I am clicking 'Ok'.

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>
> ERROR: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>   Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.